# How to profile the page render performance of ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have a page that is definitely rendering slower than others. It's not doing any remote calls. Slow enough that users have mentioned it feels "sluggish" compared to how fast the other page renders are. What strategies exist for profiling this render so I can optimize it?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the first thing I do is to log bindings. Often binding updates are firing more often that you expect and it can really slow things down.

```
Ember.LOG_BINDINGS = true
```

Beyond that you might want to use the Ember Instrumentation module. There is a great blog post on this technique [here](http://tobyho.com/2013/03/12/perf-testing-ember.js-views/) but the basic idea is:

```
Ember.subscribe('render', {
  before: function(name, start, payload){
    return start
  },
  after: function(name, end, payload, start){
    var duration = Math.round(end - start)
    var template = payload.template
    if (template){ // this is to filter out anonymous templates
      console.log('rendered', template, 'took', duration, 'ms')
    }
  }
})
```